# Tensorflow Object Detection API (detect small object in 720x1280 image)

Tags: object, deep-learning, detection, vision

### **Problem: Can't detect a small object (Flying Drone) in 720x1280 frame.**

- **Library: TensorFlow Object Detection API**
- **Model: SSD MobileNet V1 COCO**
- **Dataset: 260,000 Train | 10,000 Test (both 720x1280)**
- **The object has sizes between 25x25 to 60x60. It has only one class.**

**Question 1:** [SSD_MobileNet_V1_COCO](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config) has a parameter `image_resizer` is 300x300. Does that mean the 720x1280 frame is resized before inputting into convolution layers?

**Question 2:** Do you suggest slicing the dataset into smaller regions with the object in it on randomized location and then feeding those slices as train/test set would help detecting the small object?